# Reading 2D array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, text-files

I want to read from a 2D array text file looking like this.This is the code that I wrote. I am creating a game board. The first line represents the dimensions of the board so the program must only read from the second line onwards.

I have attempted numerous ways of doing this such as using the scanner function etc. I was told by a friend of mine that my approach is wrong. How would I fix this code to do that particular function?

```
7 7
.......
.......
....x..
....x..
....x..
...xx..
...sx.t
```

```
public class hey {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

    }

    public static  String[][] read() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bo = new BufferedReader(new("board_01.txt"));
        int column = Integer.parseInt(bo.readLine());
        int row = Integer.parseInt(bo.readLine());
        String[][] map = new String[row][column];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            String line = bo.readLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                map[i][j] = String.valueOf(line.charAt(j));
            }
        } 
        bo.close();
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Please excuse my indentation I am still working on perfecting it. "* Most IDEs have a shortcut for formatting (indenting etc.) code.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
int column = Integer.parseInt(bo.readLine());

int row = Integer.parseInt(bo.readLine());
```

This tries to read two ints on two separate lines, but that is not how your file is set up -- instead the 2 leading ints on one line, the first line

Instead you should have :

```
int column = bo.readInt();    
int row = bo.readInt();
bo.readLine();
```

You read the 2 ints in the first row, and the capture and swallow the end-of-line token so that the Scanner moves to the next line

Also, your main method cannot be empty, otherwise your program won't do anything at all.

Comment: Thank really appreciate you help . My return type is correct ,right? and how must I populate my main method ?

Comment: @king123456: You will want to test your code to find out if the return type works. And regarding the main method, you should first try to figure this out yourself. I have faith that you will likely succeed on  your first, second or third attempt. Good luck!